# Accessing Upload Data in React From Multer Node Server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, upload, multer

So I figured out how to upload files using React and Node. It appears to be working, but I'm still very new to this stuff, and I can't quite understand how to access the file I just uploaded in React. I want to have it so that you use a form in React to upload a zip file, and then I want to have some scripts unzip the uploaded file and perform some actions on the contents. I have my files uploading properly, but I'm not sure how to pass the filename data into React after upload..

My server file:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
const path = require('path');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {

    cb(null, './src/uploads');
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {


    const newFilename = `${uuidv4()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`;
    cb(null, newFilename);
  },
});

var fileFilter = function (req, file, cb) {

   if (
    file.mimetype !== 'application/zip'
    ) {

      req.fileValidationError = 'goes wrong on the mimetype';
      return cb(new Error('mimetype does not match application/zip. upload rejected'));
   }
   console.log('>> fileFilter good = ',file.mimetype)
   cb(null, true);
  }

const upload = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: fileFilter });

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/', upload.single('selectedFile'), (req, res) => {

  res.send();
});


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`));
```

My React File:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class UserForm extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      description: '',
      selectedFile: '',
    };
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    switch (e.target.name) {
      case 'selectedFile':
        this.setState({ selectedFile: e.target.files[0] });
        break;
      default:
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { description, selectedFile } = this.state;
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('description', description);
    formData.append('selectedFile', selectedFile);

    console.log('form data ',formData)

    axios.post('/', formData)
      .then((result) => {
        console.log('>> (onSubmit) file upload result = ',result);
        // access results...
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('>> ERROR FILE UPLAOD ',error);
        alert('File upload failed. Please ensure you are uploading a .zip file only')
      })
  }

  render() {
    const { description, selectedFile } = this.state;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="description"
          value={description}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <input
          type="file"
          name="selectedFile"
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default UserForm;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you are uploading a single file. So you need to return it from your `/` route like this

```
app.post('/', upload.single('selectedFile'), (req, res) => {
  res.send( req.file );
});
```

When you use Multer and upload a file like this, then `req.file` will be your uploaded file here, which is `selectedFile`. So, you need to return it to use where ever you want.

This `req.file` has some information like `originalname, filename, path` and so on. You can use those information on your front-end. For example, you can grab `path` (which is the full path of the uploaded file) then use it in an `<img>` element.

Specifically for your situation, you can hold an `imagePath` state:

```
this.state = {
      description: '',
      selectedFile: '',
      imagePath: '',
};
```

Then update your state within your axois' `.then` method:

```
axios.post('/', formData)
    .then((result) => {
        this.setState({imagePath: result.data.path})
})
....
```

and use it in your component:

```
{this.state.imagePath && <img src={this.state.imagePath} /> }
```

This is a very simple example, logic can be more complex when your app gets bigger.